# Google Voice to Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, audio

I am currently doing a voice recognition project. Any idea how to transfer google voice library to rp2 ?

Comment: Transfer how? Physically copy it to the Pi?

Comment: Yes @SteveRobillard

Comment: Why can't you transfer it like any other file SSH, flash drive, dropbox etc.?

Comment: @ShunJian Is anything keeping you from doing `git clone git://github.com/Geczy/google-voice-library.git` on the Pi?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you could do:

Download the Google voice library onto your computer. Then copy it to a form of removable storage, such as a desktop hard drive or memory stick. Then plug the removable storage into one of the Pi's USB ports, making sure your Raspberry Pi is sufficiently powered. You can then simply copy the information across to the Pi.

Alternatively once you have downloaded your files you could use a program like FileZilla to transfer the files across to the Pi over your network. (Ideally you want your computer and Pi on the same network for this, it makes the process much easier).

Dropbox or another file sharing site is an option, just be aware that you have to first upload the files from your computer to the internet. Then download the files using the Pi, depending on your internet connection speed this might be impractical. It is also going to take the longest to transfer the files out of all the options listed here.